# How to get files from Web Directory in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am working on on my projects where i want to load images from Web Server Directory. There are no of images which are i want to show in grid. How can i achieve this? Please help me. I need solution for Cross Platform. Building app for iOs and Android.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/

Comment: i don't know my image name. it is unknown. so how can i get filename, ext etc..

Comment: You want to load images off a remote server, but don't know their name?

Comment: yes their names are generated by the system. these are unique sequences and cant be tracked.

Comment: Do you have access to the server?  If so, you need to create a service (or something) that will expose the names of the images.  Otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: i had created HTTPWebservice but for PCL projects some methods are not available. Then i tried RESTSharp but it incompatible for framework 4.5. Really annoying task.